There is program which classifies whether email is spam or ham
There is program which classifies whether email is spam or ham and I am using train and test split in it and I want only class spam to be taken into train and test split module.
def readFiles(path):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            inBody = False
            lines = []
            f = io.open(path, 'r', encoding='latin1')
            for line in f:
                if inBody:
                    lines.append(line)
                elif line == '\n':
                    continue
            f.close()
            message = '\n'.join(lines)
            yield path, message


def dataFrameFromDirectory(path, classification):
    rows = []
    index = []
    for filename, message in readFiles(path):
        rows.append({'class': classification})
        index.append(filename)

    return DataFrame(rows, index=index)

data = DataFrame({'class': []})
data = pd.concat([data, dataFrameFromDirectory("path\\spam", "spam")])
data = pd.concat([data, dataFrameFromDirectory("path\\ham", "ham")])
data.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data,data,
                                                 random_state=104,
                                                 test_size=0.20,
                                                 shuffle=True
                                                 )

print('X_train: ')
print(X_train.head())
print('')
print('X_test: ')
print(X_test.head())
print('')
print('y_train: ')
print(y_train.head())
print('')
print('y_test: ')
print(y_test.head())

I am having bit of idea that there would be if-elseif statement would be used but I don't know if you can't differentiate the data like this in train and test module and yes there are files which is stored in my PC and with the help of those files it differentiates and classifies the each mail based on its content (head line and message).

I don't understand what does "only class spam to be taken into train and test split module" means. You need at least two classes to train any model

Not sure why you just want the spam classes but you could just make the dataframe for the spam classes by itself and provide that to the train/test split.
data_base = DataFrame({'class': []})
spam = pd.concat([data_base, dataFrameFromDirectory("path\\spam", "spam")])
ham = pd.concat([data_base, dataFrameFromDirectory("path\\ham", "ham")])
data = pd.concat([spam, ham])
data.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(spam,spam,
                                                 random_state=104,
                                                 test_size=0.20,
                                                 shuffle=True
                                                 )

This would give you all the spam data, and still let you access the whole dataset later on
